# Angular Jasmine Test Timeout

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, karma-jasmine

I am working on an Ionic Angular project and keep getting intermittent failing unit tests for various different tests due to a timeout. Oddly enough, these are just the 'should create' tests that come default with the spec file creation.

`Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)`

I have read a few related articles/Stack Overflow posts, but none seem to resolve this issue. It's very hard to isolate the issue because sometimes it runs fine, and others it times out. This is happening for a few different tests, but I will provide an example of one of the most basic failing tests.

**Component**

```
export class MenuItemCardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() menuItem: MenuItem

  constructor(private firebaseService: FirebaseService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadImage()
  }

  loadImage() {
    this.firebaseService.loadImage(this.menuItem.id, "menuItems").then(url => {
      this.menuItem.imageUrl = url
    })
  }

}
```

**Service Function** (this.storage var is firebase.storage.Storage)

```
async loadImage(id: string, ref: string) {
    return this.storage.ref(ref).child(`${id}`).getDownloadURL().catch(() => { /* console.log(`Error getting menuItem id: ${error.code}`) */ })
}
```

**Spec File**

```
describe('MenuItemCardComponent', () => {
  let component: MenuItemCardComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MenuItemCardComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MenuItemCardComponent ],
      imports: [IonicModule.forRoot()]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MenuItemCardComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.menuItem = {
      title: "Menu Item",
      price: "3.50"
    }
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: The `menuItem` that you set to your component under test does not have an `id` property that is needed by `loadImage`. And if `loadImage` is accessing a remote server, you should be providing a test double for FirebaseService instead of using the real service, so that the result of your test does not depend on the availability of the remote resource.

Answer (score 2):

jfd348 is absolutely right. It seems that the times it does time out, the `loadImage` method call took longer than 5 seconds. To fix it, you have to provide a stub.

Try this:

```
describe('MenuItemCardComponent', () => {
  let component: MenuItemCardComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MenuItemCardComponent>;
  // add this line
  let mockFirebaseService: jasmine.SpyObj<FirebaseService>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    // and this one
    // The first string is optional but I provide it for debugging purposes
    // and the second array strings are the public methods you would like to mock
    mockFirebaseService = jasmine.createSpyObj<FirebaseService>('FirebaseService', ['loadImage']);
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MenuItemCardComponent ],
      imports: [IonicModule.forRoot()],
      providers: [
        // provide the mock for the real FirebaseService
        { provide: FirebaseService, useValue: mockFirebaseService }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MenuItemCardComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.menuItem = {
      title: "Menu Item",
      price: "3.50"
    }
    // the first fixture.detectChanges calls ngOnInit so we have to provide
    // the results of loadImage before it
    mockFirebaseService.loadImage.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve('xyz'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

With those changes, the test should not have `async` timeouts.

Comment: thanks for your response! I was actually able to do something similar to get it to work by using spyOn, to return a mock value from the service functions. Your approach does seem to work, just confused how the test ever passed if there was never an id to make the firebase call successful?

Comment: When we use mocks and spies, we don't care about the arguments of the method/function because we go straight to the return value.

Comment: Right, I understand that part. I'm wondering how this was working for me before using the spy. The failing test I provided in the initial question only failed about half the time my test suite ran. I plan on using spies moving forward, just trying to understand how it previously worked.

Comment: It was working previously half the time because it would actually be making API calls and if the API call resolved within 5 seconds, the test would pass but if it didn't resolve within 5 seconds, the test would fail. That's what I think was happening.